# Electron momentum in a one-dimensional lattice and conservation issue

Tags: condensed-matter, momentum, symmetry, conservation-laws, crystals

A one-dimensional lattice is a periodic array of atoms or ions where any two adjacent ions are separated by a fixed distance, the lattice spacing $a$. The Hamiltonian of an electron moving in this lattice is $$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\hat{V}(\hat{x})$$ where the potential is periodic $V(x+a)=V(x)$. The translation operator is $$\hat{T}_a=e^{-i\hat{p}a/\hbar}$$ where $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\partial_x$ is the momentum operator and acting on a function $f(x)$ it translates the argument by amount $a$ i.e. $\hat{T}_af(x)=f(x+a)$. Due to the discrete translational symmetry of the Hamiltonian, $$[\hat{H},\hat{T}_a]=0,$$ from which it follows that $$a[\hat{H},\hat{p}]=0.$$ But since $a\neq 0$, implies $$[\hat{H},\hat{p}]=0$$ i.e., momentum is conserved or the expectation value of momentum is conserved.

But this is plain wrong because the lattice does not have continuous translational symmetry, and momentum cannot be conserved. After all, the electron is subjected to a non-uniform potential. What's the flaw in this calculation?